# Grouping by column of lists in pandas GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following `df`,

```
pri_key          doc_no    c_code
[9001, 7620]     767       0090
[9001, 7620]     767       0090
[9002, 7530]     768       4100
[9002, 7530]     769       3000
[9003, 7730]     777       4000
[9003, 7730]     777       4000
[9003, 7730]     779       4912
```

I need to hash `pri_key` then groupby hashed `pri_key`, and excludes groups whose rows have the same `doc_no` and `c_code` combination from `df`;

```
 df["doc_group"] = df['pri_key'].apply(lambda ls: hash(tuple(sorted(ls))))

 grouped = df.groupby("doc_group")

 m = grouped[['doc_no', 'c_code']].apply(lambda x: len(np.unique(x.values)) > 1)

 df = df.loc[m]
```

but it did not work,

```
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match
```

I am wondering how to solve this. So the result will look like,

```
pri_key          doc_no    c_code
[9002, 7530]     768       4100
[9002, 7530]     769       3000
[9003, 7730]     777       4000
[9003, 7730]     777       4000
[9003, 7730]     779       4912
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tupleize and hash `pri_key`, then use it to group on `df`:

```
grouper = [hash(tuple(x)) for x in df['pri_key']]
df[df.groupby(grouper)[['doc_no', 'c_code']].transform('nunique').gt(1).all(1)]

        pri_key  doc_no  c_code
2  [9002, 7530]     768    4100
3  [9002, 7530]     769    3000
4  [9003, 7730]     777    4000
5  [9003, 7730]     777    4000
6  [9003, 7730]     779    4912
```

Comment: is it able to generate a boolean mask for `transform('nunique').gt(1)` and apply back to the `df`?

Comment: @daiyue Yes, `transform` broadcasts the result back to the original DataFrame so you can use it to filter.